# Elasticsearch Inconsistent facet counts

Tags: elasticsearch

I seem to to be experiencing some inconsistent facet counts, and I was wondering why there is a difference between the two. I ran the two queries below and you can see at least one of the terms has a slightly different count (see term 21 towards the bottom) 948 vs 1035 is the difference. Term 43 at the very bottom has a delta as well.

Query #1:

```
{'facets': {'primary_country_id': {'terms': {'field': 'primary_country_id', 'size': '20'}}}}
```

Query #1:

```
{'facets': {'primary_country_id': {'terms': {'field': 'primary_country_id', 'size': '30'}}}}
```

Results from Query #1:

```
{
  "primary_country_id": {
    "_type": "terms",
    "missing": 3475,
    "total": 312111,
    "other": 4460,
    "terms": [
      {
        "term": 41,
        "count": 187293
      },
      {
        "term": 9,
        "count": 24177
      },
      {
        "term": 50,
        "count": 17200
      },
      {
        "term": 15,
        "count": 13015
      },
      {
        "term": 30,
        "count": 10296
      },
      {
        "term": 32,
        "count": 8824
      },
      {
        "term": 6,
        "count": 7703
      },
      {
        "term": 23,
        "count": 7502
      },
      {
        "term": 2,
        "count": 5614
      },
      {
        "term": 33,
        "count": 5214
      },
      {
        "term": 16,
        "count": 4691
      },
      {
        "term": 24,
        "count": 3560
      },
      {
        "term": 31,
        "count": 3126
      },
      {
        "term": 7,
        "count": 2748
      },
      {
        "term": 12,
        "count": 1430
      },
      {
        "term": 19,
        "count": 1403
      },
      {
        "term": 8,
        "count": 1342
      },
      {
        "term": 46,
        "count": 1052
      },
      {
        "term": 21,
        "count": 948
      },
      {
        "term": 43,
        "count": 513
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Results from Query #2:

```
{
  "primary_country_id": {
    "_type": "terms",
    "missing": 3475,
    "total": 312111,
    "other": 0,
    "terms": [
      {
        "term": 41,
        "count": 187293
      },
      {
        "term": 9,
        "count": 24177
      },
      {
        "term": 50,
        "count": 17200
      },
      {
        "term": 15,
        "count": 13015
      },
      {
        "term": 30,
        "count": 10296
      },
      {
        "term": 32,
        "count": 8824
      },
      {
        "term": 6,
        "count": 7703
      },
      {
        "term": 23,
        "count": 7502
      },
      {
        "term": 2,
        "count": 5614
      },
      {
        "term": 33,
        "count": 5214
      },
      {
        "term": 16,
        "count": 4691
      },
      {
        "term": 24,
        "count": 3560
      },
      {
        "term": 31,
        "count": 3126
      },
      {
        "term": 7,
        "count": 2748
      },
      {
        "term": 12,
        "count": 1430
      },
      {
        "term": 19,
        "count": 1403
      },
      {
        "term": 8,
        "count": 1342
      },
      {
        "term": 46,
        "count": 1052
      },
      {
        "term": 21,
        "count": 1035
      },
      {
        "term": 43,
        "count": 910
      },
      {
        "term": 22,
        "count": 906
      },
      {
        "term": 13,
        "count": 717
      },
      {
        "term": 28,
        "count": 690
      },
      {
        "term": 38,
        "count": 415
      },
      {
        "term": 26,
        "count": 352
      },
      {
        "term": 37,
        "count": 295
      },
      {
        "term": 25,
        "count": 208
      },
      {
        "term": 34,
        "count": 207
      },
      {
        "term": 4,
        "count": 94
      },
      {
        "term": 48,
        "count": 92
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that can happen in any distributed system, as mentioned in the other answer there's a [github issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1305) for it. The only 100% guaranteed solution is to go for a single shard, which does not scale though.

The problem manifests itself with high cardinality fields, fields that have a high amount of unique terms. You can use the `shard_size` parameter to control how many facet entries will be requested per shard, which can differ from the `size` (default 10) that tells how many entries you get back. For instance having `size` set to `10` and `shard_size` set to `100` should make things better already, but doesn't guarantee that you get all the counts totally accurate, it just reduces the chance that you see wrong counts. Whether you still get back wrong counts depends on the cardinality of the fields you facet on. You can imagine that if a field has 100 unique terms, `shard_size` set to `100` would guarantee to have perfect counts all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just run into this issue: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1305